# How to put constructor contents in another file and execute the content from the class constructor

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working with Tkinter. I have a class. I am configuring rows and columns in the constructor of that class, but I want to put this configuring in an other file and import that.

My code looks like this :

**main.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Config:
    def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = root
    self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    selfroot.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

root = Tk()
obj = Config(root)
root.mainloop()
```

But I want to achieve this :

**main.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Config:
    def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = root
    
root = Tk()
obj = Config(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**config.py**

```
self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
selfroot.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class should inherit directly from `Tk`, instead of passing an instance of it  around in your functions and storing the instance in an attribute of your class. And your class names should be more descriptive. In `Root.__init__` call the config function and pass it the `Root` class itself. Following code should work

#### main.py

```py
from tkinter import *
import config

class Root(Tk): # inherit from Tk directly instead of passing a Tk instance around in your functions
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self) # initiate Tk
        config.configure(self)
    
root = Root()
root.mainloop()
```

#### config.py

```py
def configure(cls):
    cls.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    cls.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: but then how i create object to work further, like i want to work as ( frame1 = Frame(self.root, width=200, height=100) )

Comment: @HabibUrRehman if you want to make the frame in the constructor, `self.frame1 = Frame(self, width=...)`, if in the configure function, `cls.frame1 = Frame(cls, width=...)`, if in main code `frame1 = Frame(root, width=...)`

Comment: how to create widgets in Tk.__init__(self) or root window

Comment: please can help me. Give me your email i send you the file

Comment: @HabibUrRehman programmer.anonymous@yandex.com

Answer (score 0):

main.py

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from config import config_fun

class Config:
    def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = config_fun(root)
    
root = Tk()
obj = Config(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Config.py

```
def config_fun(root):
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    return root
```

Comment: for root that is working fine but when put code for frames in config.py it did not worked correctly

Comment: I don't see frames in the code you posted